# Contour integration in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

How to carry out the following integration?$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^6}{(x^4+a^4)^2}dx$$I tried doing it using contour integration but it turned out to be extremely complicated. A help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. It is perfectly possible that it is not as complicated as you thought. In any case, you should show what you tried in order to get constructive help: this way, someone else can point your mistake, or if no mistakes were made, point out how to continue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\int _0^{\infty }\frac{x^6}{\left(x^4+a^4\right)^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206701/evaluate-int-0-infty-fracx6-leftx4a4-right2dx) Seems to use both contour integrals and other methods e.g. Ramanujan's master theorem, for instance. In general, for integration of rational functions there are quite a few real-analytic methods available.

Comment: By the way, the contour the question-asker uses in the linked post is the large semicircular contour (they don’t show this). You should convince yourself that the contribution along the arc vanishes

Comment: @Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer Thanks a lot sir! That was really helpful. It was what i exactly needed

Comment: Oh, thanks for the feedback, good to have been of service here.

Comment: @FShrike True sir. i should have written what i actually did. But i am new here and do not have much idea on how to write all that math. Without using mathjax, here's what i did : if a is root of function f(x) then (x-a) is a factor of f(x). Using this theorem i wrote (z^4+a^4) in the factorized form. And then tried to find out the residue of f(z). Since there are four factors of (z^4+a^4), everything turned out to be insanely complex.

Comment: Ah @user231188 You can simplify such calculations using, for example, derivatives of the polynomial, or sum-of-roots formulae

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^6}{(x^4+a^4)^2}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto az}{=}\frac{1}{|a|}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^6 \,dz}{(z^4+1)^2}\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\frac{3}{4|a|}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^2}{1+z^4}\,dz$$
equals (by applying the substitution $z\mapsto 1/z$ on the subinterval $(1,+\infty)$ of the integration range)
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{3}{4|a|}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+z^2}{1+z^4}\,dz&=&\frac{3}{4|a|}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+z^2-z^4-z^6}{1-z^8}\,dz\\ &=& \frac{3}{4|a|}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{8n+1}+\frac{1}{8n+3}-\frac{1}{8n+5}-\frac{1}{8n+7}\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
so the whole problem boils down to showing that the last (Dirichlet) series equals $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$, which can be done in a good number of ways, for instance by evaluating $-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ at the primitive $8$-th roots of unity.